# tcp connection in ngx-mqtt

Tags: angular, mqtt

I use [ngx-mqtt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mqtt) to connect to broker in angular. But the connection is only on ws (websocket) and the tcp connection is not done.

Here is part of what the publisher said about the library:

> For reasons of convenience, I removed the copied typings from mqtt.js
> and added it as a dev-dependency while still bundling the browserified
> latest version of it. This means although you have the ability to use
> mqtt, mqtts, tcp, ssl, wx or wxs as the protocol in the client
> options, you can not, because this is a browser library where you can
> not connect with something other than websockets . You also can not
> use key, cert and ca for the same reasons.

Now how can I add a tcp connection to this library?

Comment: You should post a question related to what did you try what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clearly stated in the section of the docs you included in your question. You can **ONLY** use MQTT over WebSockets when running in a web browser.

This is because the web browser sandbox only allows HTTP or WebSocket connections and not native TCP connections